# Reference a PS-Drive name longer than one character

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to reference a PS drive, which for the purpose of my script, will be longer than one character.
If I create the drive using a single character it's easy:

`New-PSDrive -Name E -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\ComputerName\FolderPath`

> PS C:\Windows\system32> e:
>
> PS e:>

However, If I create it using a longer file name, not so much. Is there a way to reference this drive in my script other than with a colon?

`New-PSDrive -Name LongName -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\ComputerName\FolderPath`

> PS C:\Windows\system32> LongName:
>
> LongName: : The term 'LongName:' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script...

Excerpt from the script:

```
$ServerNames = "Server1", "Server2"
$ServerNames | Foreach {New-PSDrive -Name $_ -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\$_\$DestFolder -Credential $mycreds}
$ServerNames | Foreach {Export-DhcpServer -File "$_`:$DestFile" -Force}
```

The reason I've created it like this, is due to the fact I can't use the '-credential' switch to export the dhcp server data file.

Comment: I get the same results, bit strange. You can just chuck "sl" before LongName and it works unfortunately don't have an explanation of why this happens.

Comment: `function LongName: { Set-Location $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name }`

Comment: To add to PetSerAls comment - take a look at $function with `dir function:`, or the details for a specific one with `$Function:C:`

Answer (score 0):

This is successful on a local drive.

```
New-PSDrive -Name LnameToTempFolder -PSProvider FileSystem d:\temp
Get-PSDrive | Format-Table -AutoSize

...              
LnameToTempFolder      0.00    232.30 FileSystem  D:\temp                           
Variable                              Variable                                      
...   



New-PSDrive -Name LnameToTargetFolder -PSProvider FileSystem -Root d:\target
Get-PSDrive | Format-Table -AutoSize

Name                Used (GB) Free (GB) Provider    Root               CurrentLocation
----                --------- --------- --------    ----               ---------------
...              
LnameToTargetFolder      0.00    232.30 FileSystem  D:\target                         
LnameToTempFolder        0.00    232.30 FileSystem  D:\temp                           
...
```

And successful on a remote server using the default C$ share

```
New-PSDrive -Name LnameToTempRemoteFolder -PSProvider FileSystem '\\ws01\C$\Temp'
Get-PSDrive | Format-Table -AutoSize

...              
LnameToTempRemoteFolder                     FileSystem  \\ws01\C$\Temp                
...


cd LnameToTargetFolder:


Get-ChildItem


Directory: D:\target


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----      Sun 07 Jan 02018                     20171126
```

This are on Win 10 and WS2K12R2

If you are on earlier version of the OS, the may be and issue. I do not anything below the above to validate.

Or this is an environmental issue on you side of things.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, your sample code worked just fine for me

```
 New-PSDrive -Name LongName -PSProvider FileSystem -Root C:\
```

instead of `LongName:` you should be using something like `CD LongName:` as there is a built in function for single letter drive names, but not others.

My guess is your sample code and your script are having different issues. 
What is the error you're getting from that snippit of the script?